# Xamarin Forms - How to create simple orderlist/carting?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My application is online ordering for a cafe

this is the the menu where you can choose  foods to order and if you tapped it, the pop up will display to input the quantity.

And also in the top right you can see a cart logo if you tap it the page will  move to cart/orderlist page where you can see all of your current order

**Screenshot of OrdernowMenu**
[image: Menus]
Link:https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxVU2.jpg

basically what i want to happen is if you input quantity and tap "OK" it will display/add automatically in the cart 
**This image is the popup when you select a menu.**
[image: Popup of quantity]
Link:https://i.stack.imgur.com/mECd1.jpg

**My codes**

**OrdernowMenu.xaml.cs**

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Icon="cartimage.png" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"></ToolbarItem>

    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ListView x:Name="MyOrder" ItemSelected="MyOrder_ItemSelected" RowHeight="100">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
                            <Image Source="{Binding menu_image ,StringFormat='https://i.imgur.com/{0:F0}.png'}"  Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="{Binding menu_name}" Font="30"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding menu_price,StringFormat='₱ {0:F0}'}" Font="20"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding menu_availability} " Font="10" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**OrdernowMenu.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class OrdernowMenu : ContentPage
    {
        public string json_response { get; set; }
        public string tester { get; set; }
        public string seletedMenu { get; set; }
        public string menuPrice { get; set; }
        public string quantity { get; set; }
        public string myinput { get; set; }

        public OrdernowMenu(PostSender posts1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            json_response = posts1.response;
            tester = posts1.teststring;
            GetUserAsync();
        }



        private async Task GetUserAsync()
        {

            var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Menus>>(json_response);

            MyOrder.ItemsSource = user;


        }



        public async Task MyOrder_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            var selectedOrder = e.SelectedItem as Menus;

            if (selectedOrder != null)

            seletedMenu = selectedOrder.menu_name;
            menuPrice = selectedOrder.menu_price;


             myinput = await InputBox(this.Navigation);

            quantity = myinput;




        }

        public static Task<string> InputBox(INavigation navigation)
        {
            // wait in this proc, until user did his input 
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

            var lblTitle = new Label { Text = "Input ", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,  };
            var lblMessage = new Label { Text = "Quantity" };
            var txtInput = new Entry { Text = "" };

            var btnOk = new Button
            {
                Text = "Ok",
                WidthRequest = 100,
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(0.8, 0.8, 0.8),
            };
            btnOk.Clicked += async (s, e) =>
            {
                // close page
                var result = txtInput.Text;
                await navigation.PopModalAsync();
                // pass result
                tcs.SetResult(result);
            };

            var btnCancel = new Button
            {
                Text = "Cancel",
                TextColor = Color.White,

                WidthRequest = 100,
                   BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(0.8, 0.8, 0.8)
              //  BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#ff5300")

            };
            btnCancel.Clicked += async (s, e) =>
            {
                // close page
                await navigation.PopModalAsync();
                // pass empty result
                tcs.SetResult(null);
            };

            var slButtons = new StackLayout
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                Children = { btnOk, btnCancel },
            };

            var layout = new StackLayout
            {
               // BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#ff5300"),
                Padding = new Thickness(0, 40, 0, 0),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                Children = { lblTitle, lblMessage, txtInput, slButtons },
            };

            // create and show page
            var page = new ContentPage();
            page.Content = layout;
            navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
            // open keyboard
            txtInput.Focus();

            // code is waiting her, until result is passed with tcs.SetResult() in btn-Clicked
            // then proc returns the result
            return tcs.Task;
        }




public void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           // DisplayAlert("Tester", seletedMenu + menuPrice + quantity, "OK");

            Carting cart = new Carting()
            {
                menuname = seletedMenu,
                price = menuPrice,
                qty = quantity
            };

            var viewcart = new OrderCart();
            viewcart.BindingContext = cart;

            Navigation.PushAsync(viewcart);

        }
```

This is my Listview to my Cart/Orderlist.
My problem is i can't display all of my order i think the logic of my code is wrong. currently it still blank i can't find a way to display my orders please help it should display Menu name ,quantity  and price.

**This screenshot is OrderCart.xaml it's blank because i can't pass data to listview**

[image: Current Cart]
Link:https://i.stack.imgur.com/waMhp.jpg

**Ordercart.xaml**

```
<ListView x:Name="MyCart" ItemSelected="MyCart_ItemSelected"  RowHeight="50">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell >
                    <Grid>



                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label  Text="{Binding menuname}" Font="40" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            <Label  Text="{Binding price}" Font="20" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            <Label  Text="{Binding qty }" Font="15" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        </StackLayout>


                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

**Ordercart.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class OrderCart : ContentPage
    {
        public OrderCart ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        private void MyCart_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Concept to Cart/Orderlist
note: don't mind the lines i just want to display the menu name quantity and price.

**this screenshot is only a concept to the thrid screenshot
and this is what i want to happen**
[image: concept]
Link:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te9Zd.jpg

Comment: please edit your question and simplify it.  There are too many screenshots - I can't tell which image corresponds to which xaml/cs.  And don't tell us about everything you want your app to do (which makes your question too broad to answer), just focus on the immediate problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Agree with Json this is too much to follow :)

Comment: i thought stackoverflow wants a thread to be specific and detailed.

Comment: i added details to the screenshots @Jason

Comment: my question is not broad i just told the process

Comment: there is a difference between "detailed" and "useless detail"

Comment: you are creating the OrderCart page and setting it's BindingContext, but you are never setting the ItemsSource for the ListView.

Comment: and that's my question i don't know how to create that .

Comment: But that's not what you asked us. You asked "How to create simple orderlist/carting?" which is a very broad question.

Comment: i'm sorry i don't speak english very well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, pass the data to display via the contstructor

```
public partial class OrderCart : ContentPage
{
    List<Carting> _data;

    public OrderCart (List<Carting> data)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

         _data = data;

         MyOrder.ItemsSource = data;
    }
```

then when calling OrderCart

```
        var data = new List<Carting>();
        data.Add(cart);
        var viewcart = new OrderCart(data);
        Navigation.PushAsync(viewcart);
```

Comment: i have a question.

Comment: it's only showing your current order and the code doesn't stack it if i have 2 orders, how do you add another order? i tried this

`List<Carting> _data;

    public OrderCart (List<Carting> data)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

       //  _data  += data;      doesn't work

         MyOrder.ItemsSource = _data;
    }`